# How to make this python(2.7) scripts works with unicode filename?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I have the following script to process filenames with non-latin characters:

```
import os
filelst = []
allfile = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for file in allfile:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            filelst.append(file)

w = open(os.getcwd()+'\\_filelist.txt','w+')

for file in allfile:
    w.write(file)
    w.write("\n")
w.close()
```

---

filelist in my folder:

```
new 1.py
ああっ女神さまっ 小っちゃいって事は便利だねっ.1998.Ep0108.x264.AC3CalChi.avi
ああっ女神さまっ 小っちゃいって事は便利だねっ.1998.Ep0108.x264.AC3CalChi.srt
```

output in _filelist.txt:

```
new 1.py
???????? ??????????????.1998.Ep01-08.x264.AC3-CalChi.avi
???????? ??????????????.1998.Ep01-08.x264.AC3-CalChi.srt
```

Comment: I've removed a number of filenames entries to work around the strange SO validation exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the list of files as Unicode strings instead by passing a Unicode file path to `listdir`. As you're using getcwd, use: `os.getcwdu()`

Then open your output file with a text encoding wrapper. `io` module is the new way to do this (`io` handles Universal newlines correctly).

Putting it all together:

```
import os
import io

filelst = []
allfile = os.listdir(os.getcwdu())
for file in allfile:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            filelst.append(file)

w = io.open(os.getcwd()+'\\_filelist.txt','w+', encoding="utf-8")

for file in allfile:
    w.write(file)
    w.write("\n")
w.close()
```

In Windows and OS X, this will just work as filename translation is enforced. In Linux, a filename can be any encoding (or non at all!). Therefore, ensure that whatever is creating your files (avi + srt), is using UTF-8, your terminal is set to UTF-8 and your locale is UTF-8.

Comment: Oh!Thank you!You sloved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your file with a proper encoding to write unicode in it.You can use [`codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) for opening the file:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(os.getcwd()+'\\_filelist.txt','w+',encoding='your-encoding') as w:
    for file in allfile:
        w.write(file + '\n')
```

You can use `UTF-8` as your encoding which is a universal encoding or another proper encoding based on your unicode type.Also note that instead of opening the file and closing it manually you can use [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file which will close the file automatically at the end of the block.

Comment: import os[LineFeed]import codecs[LineFeed]allfile = os.listdir(os.getcwd())[LineFeed]with codecs.open(os.getcwd()+'\_filelist.txt','w+',encoding='utf-8') as w:[LineFeed][Tab]for file in allfile:[LineFeed][Tab][Tab]w.write(file + '\n')[LineFeed][LineFeed]#UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Screenshot:[Dropbox link](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AADs41Yhga-PEBxeg7ta6eZiSjvAQtd2ZNdGqd2h6nZWgw/12/91395487/png/32x32/3/1446843600/0/2/%E8%9E%A2%E5%B9%95%E6%88%AA%E5%9C%96%202015-11-07%2000.22.15.png/EMbeg0cYmAcgASgB/C8MR7H-_T0UBHfO71748IGHzCcX_LIPViZvVfDiu-fs?size_mode=5&size=32x32)